# How to I “set out” the holes for hinges?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I am thinking of building some cupboards with inset doors and solid sides (e.g not a face frame).

Are there any “trick” to how I measure the location of the holes for the hinge screws and bore?

I am assuming I will use this type of hinge, but by choose anther type if it is easyer.

[image]

Comment: I've never used hinges like that, but sometimes hardware comes with a paper template that will help you lay out the holes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to recess the hinges, you'll want to create a jig and use a router for the recess. I would recommend aligning the door and frame together and marking between the two at each hinge location as a reference point so that you don't install one at the wrong height.

When you're ready to screw in the hinge, place it on the door and frame to mark the locations of the screw holes and then drill pilot holes. Make sure your drill is level and square to the surface so you don't end up with crooked screws.

Finally, when you first attach the hinge to one side, don't tighten it all the way down, leave some play in it. Do the same when you screw it in to the other surface. Then tighten one screw on each side at a time, verifying that the door still swings freely as you go.

Answer (score 1):

Not really the best idea. but if you are drilling into Cupboard (compressed board),I don't see the need for pilot holes first. Your biggest problem is actually getting the screws to start self tapping, where the hard melamine layer is hard to pierce... therefore, I would suggest the following.

[image]

Simply get one hinge, and a piece of wood to be used for the template... drive your screws into the hinge (on your piece of template wood). You need to ensure that the screws protrude all the way through to the other side of the template (thereby exposing their sharp points. Next add a cross piece to be your depth locator... this will then be your template where you can simply place the screws against the cupboard surface and bang a few times with a rubber mallet.

once your template screw points have pierced the hard surface of the cupboard it will be an easy task to fully screw in the screws... 
The only problem, is that you will have to think of something smart with the height of each hinge in the cupboard, since i expect you will have different size doors, the vertical location of each hole may change???